# Accessing Ubuntu VM GUI over SSH remotely

Tags: remote-access

How can I access Ubuntu 14.04 VM GUI over SSH remotely? To be clearer, I don't want to run Ubuntu 14.04 on a headless VM and access over VRDP client, e.g. Remote Desktop. Rather, I'd like to log in to my specific account over SSH, but with GUI instead of being dropped into a console mode. I hope some X11 forwarding trick is there.

Comment: Regular X forwarding over SSH can't do that. You can just run applications on a remote host that display windows on and take input events from the local host with `ssh -X`.

Answer (score 1):

ssh -X will do the trick. It will forward X so that you can launch graphical apps from the remote server.

Comment: shh - X won't do. I want full screen access. I tried Xming (Full Screen Mode) on Windows 8.1, but seems it does not work.